# How do I install the Silverlight 4 beta runtime on a test machine without Visual Studio?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Can anyone tell me how to install the Silverlight 4 beta runtime on a test machine without Visual Studio?  I keep getting an error message about the beta version being expired....

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any prior betas loaded?  You'll probably need to uninstall all previous versions...

Comment: This is an older xp laptop that has never had silverlight at all.  Does it need a copy of Visual Studio installed for the beta runtime to work, or did the beta expire since the RC was released on Monday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the RC was released days before I attempted this install.  After upgrading Visual Studio and my Silverlight application to SL 4 RC (up from the beta) it installed and ran fine on the test machine.